# python3 аналог on error resume next из vba

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код вида

```
try:
    a = 3 / x
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
try:
    b = 3 / y
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
try:
    c = 3 / z
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

т.е. ошибка в одном вычислении не должна мешать вычислять остальные. В VBA можно было бы перед вычислениями прописать команду `On Error Resume Next`. А в python можно этот код сделать как-нибудь проще?

Или вообще вместо исключений лучше использовать условные операторы?

**UPD**

В процессе обсуждения выяснилось, что реальная задача всё-таки влияет на ответ. Использую `openpyxl`.

```
try:
    _ = ws.cell(row=i, column=required_columns.pp, value=pp)
except ValueError:
    pass
try:
    _ = ws.cell(row=i, column=required_columns.sum, value=sum)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

где `required_columns` - `namedtuple`, содержащий номера столбцов, в которые выводить данные. Если столбец не нужен, то его значение равно 0 и этим `try` просто его пропускаю. Возвращаемое значение нигде не используется.

Comment: Чего-то похожего на "Resume Next" в Python нет. Что у вас должно записаться в переменную если делимое равно нулю? Можно сделать примерно так (при нулевом x в a попадет `None`): `a = 3 / x if x else None`

Comment: @insolor код просто показывает общий смысл, в реальности там определённые действия производятся, но смысл понятен. Подожду, может кто еще чего предложит, а так можете оформить как ответ.

Comment: Почему в вашем случае вместо "pass" нельзя продолжить выполнять код?

Comment: @Igor не понял вопроса. Вы предлагаете следующие `try` располагать под `except`? Тогда вообще получится не то, что нужно.

Comment: скорее ближе к рекурсии, вместо pass ставим вызов функции или продолжаем вычисления, зависит от задачи. Вложенности быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.

Перевод:

> Ошибки никогда не должны игнорироваться.
>   Если не игнорированы явно.

Чтобы игнорировать исключение, возникшее в блоке кода, можно использовать [`contextlib.suppress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(SomeError):
    some_action()
    may_raise_some_error()
run_anyway()
```

`run_anyway()` выполняется даже если `some_action()` или `may_raise_some_error()` выбрасывают `SomeError` исключение. Если `some_action()` выбрасывает исключение, то `may_raise_some_error()` не выполняется.

В вашем случае:

```
with suppress(ValueError):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=required_columns.sum, value=sum)
```

Для примера с `ZeroDivisionError`, явная проверка условия [как показал @insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605160/23044) может быть более предпочтительна:

```
a = 3 / x if x else None  # a is None for falsy x
a = x and 3 / x  # a is x for falsy x
if x: #XXX AVOID IT
    a = 3 / x  # NameError for falsy x
```

Если вы знаете условия, при которых вы хотите пропустить вызов:

```
if required_columns.sum:
    ws.cell(row=i, column=required_columns.sum, value=sum)
```

Это может быть предпочтительно, особенно если вызов `ws.cell()` может иметь нежелательные побочные эффекты (создание новой ячейки).

Иногда исключение предпочтительно:

```
with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Это не подавляет ошибки доступа и выполняет одно IO действие вместо двух в случае успеха ([`os.path.exists()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a967fce5f634e5c90e3951887d27cfd3bb70e2f2/Lib/genericpath.py#L14-L22) также через исключения реализован).

Comment: Интересная фишка с `suppress`, а я для создания/удаления привык сначала в if проверить что существует/отсутствует

Answer (score 2):

Чего-то похожего на "Resume Next" в Python нет (и хорошо что нет). "Resume Next" всем прекрасен, кроме того что можно забыть обработать какое-то исключение, в итоге логика работы программы может сломаться, хотя никаких ошибок выводиться не будет.

Как вариант, можно прямо при вычислении проверить, не является ли делимое нулем:

```
a = 3 / x if x else None
b = 3 / y if y else None
c = 3 / z if z else None
```

В итоге, если одно из делимых будет нулем, то в переменную запишется None. После всех вычислений нужно будет проверить результат вычислений на `is None`, и как-то этот случай обрабатывать.

Comment: альтернативно: `a = x and 3 / x` (можно использовать, если допустимо, что `a is x` в случае falsy `x`). [Maybe “kind-of” monad in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8507200/4279)

Comment: @jfs, я думал по поводу использования `and`, но тогда результат будет 0, а это будет проблематично отличить от корректного завершения вычислений. Хотя, конечно, все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: да, конечно, поэтому я и написал выше: *"если допустимо"*

Comment: в принципе допустимо. думаю нужно было в вопросе всё-таки указать что делаю, т.к. это влияет на ответы. сейчас тогда дополню вопрос